# How to use Django form elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

I have a django app that allows users to add other users in a table via a front end. Is there anyway to use django `{{form_fields}}` in JQuery?

The code below just prints '{{ form.users }}' as text instead of the form, which contains a list of users.

```
var row = '<tr>' +
        '<td><div class="form-group ">{{ form.users }}</div></td>' +
  '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $("table").append(row);
```

Thanks,

Comment: I assume this code is part of a .js file? If so, that's the issue as the JS code is not run through Python in order for the values to be injected in to the content. For this to work you will need to run it in a location where the Python logic will be interpreted - I assume in a .html page.

Comment: In addition to the above comment I would like to add that you really should not be rendering into JavaScript using Django template language for safety reasons. A form field rendered by Django is very simple you can simply write it out yourself or simply render it somewhere as hidden and just clone it via JavaScript when needed.

Comment: try saving it in some variable i.e : `var user = "{{ form.users }}"`  and then append `"+user+"` see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rory McCrossan,

Taking it out of the .js file and putting in the HTML worked